# How to solve java.lang.RuntimeException: The P3D renderer is not in the class path. while running Processing from Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, processing

I'll post the whole code:

```
import controlP5.ControlP5;
import processing.core.*;
import processing.core.PApplet;
import processing.core.PFont;
import processing.core.PImage;
import processing.core.PShape;
import processing.event.MouseEvent; 

import processing.data.*; 
import processing.event.*; 
import processing.opengl.*; 

public class Two_Maps_Texture extends PApplet {

PFont title;
PFont label;
PImage worldMap;
PImage skyBackground;
PShape box;
Table table, table2;
int rowCount;
float x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2;

//Interaction Zoom and Pan Variables:
float zoom = 600;
float panLeft = 0;
float panTop = 0;


DestinationToTrip fromUSA;
DestinationToTrip toUSA;

ControlP5 button1;
ControlP5 button2;
boolean isFromUSAVisible = false;
boolean isToUSAVisible = false;


public void setup() {

  table = new Table("From_USA_Coordinates.tsv");
  table2 = new Table("To_USA.tsv");
  rowCount = table.getRowCount();

  worldMap = loadImage("world.topo.bathy.200406.3x5400x2700.jpg"); 
  //skyBackground = loadImage("Screen-Shot-2018-04-28-at-7.46.41-PM");
  //skyBackground.resize(1400, 800);
  worldMap.resize(500, 300);
  textureMode(NORMAL);
  fill(255);
  //stroke(color(44,48,32));
  box = createShape(BOX, -650, 300, 0);
  box.beginShape(BOX);
  box.endShape();  
  box.setTexture(worldMap);

  fromUSA = new DestinationToTrip(table);
  toUSA = new DestinationToTrip(table2);

  title = loadFont("Tahoma-Bold-48.vlw");
  label = loadFont("Tahoma-48.vlw");

  fill(150);

  //pushMatrix();
    camera();
    button1 = new ControlP5(this);
    button1.addButton("From_USA_to_Other_Countries").setValue(1).setPosition((100), (height-150)).setSize(200, 100).setColorBackground(color(76,112,170)).setVisible(true);

    button2 = new ControlP5(this);
    button2.addButton("From_Other_Countries_to_USA").setValue(0).setPosition((350), (height-150)).setSize(200, 100).setColorBackground(color(76,112,170));
  //popMatrix();
}

public void draw() {  
  background(0xff181c70);  
  fill(0);  
  titlesAndLegends(); 
  boxSetup();

  if(isFromUSAVisible == true) {
      fromUSA.displayCurves(table, 0xff4185bf);
  }

  if(isToUSAVisible == true){
    pushMatrix();
      toUSA.displayCurves(table2, 0xffdfb34a);
    popMatrix();
  }
}

public void boxSetup(){
   camera(panLeft, zoom , zoom, panLeft, -190, panTop, 0, 1, 0);   // eye(0, 600, 600) center(0, 0, 0) up(0, 1, 0)

  pushMatrix();
    translate(-350, 0, 0);
    shape(box);
  popMatrix();  

  pushMatrix();
    translate(350, 0, 0);
    shape(box);
  popMatrix();  
}

public void titlesAndLegends() {
  pushMatrix();
    camera();
    textAlign(CENTER);
    textSize(40);
    fill(0xff91cd83);   
    textFont(title);
    text("Flights Involving USA - 2019", width/2, 90);  
    textFont(label);
    if(isFromUSAVisible == true) {
      textSize(20);
      fill(0xff4185bf);
      text("USA to Other Country", width/2, 150);
    } if(isToUSAVisible == true) {
      textSize(20);
      fill(0xffdfb34a);
      text("Other Countries to USA", width/2, 180);
    }
  popMatrix();
}

public void mouseDragged() {
  if((mouseX- pmouseX) > 0){
    panLeft -= 5;
  } else {
    panLeft += 5;
  }
}

public void mouseWheel(MouseEvent event) {
  float e = event.getCount();
  if(e == 1) {
    zoom += 30;
  }else {
    zoom -= 30;
  } 
}

public void From_USA_to_Other_Countries() {
  if(!isFromUSAVisible) {
    isFromUSAVisible = true;
  }else {
    isFromUSAVisible = false;
  }
}

public void From_Other_Countries_to_USA() {
  if(!isToUSAVisible) {
    isToUSAVisible = true;
  }else {
    isToUSAVisible = false;
  }
}
class DestinationToTrip {

  Table table;
  int rowCount;
  float x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2;

  int stroke = 0xffF05252;



  DestinationToTrip(Table table) {      
    this.table = table;    
  }

  public void displayCurves(Table table, int stroke) {   
    rowCount = table.getRowCount();
    table = new Table("From_USA_Coordinates.tsv");

  pushMatrix();
    // To use the center of the left box as center coordinates
    translate(-350, 0, 0);    
    textSize(15);

  for(int row = 1; row < rowCount; row++) {

    float USALatitude = table.getFloat(row, 3);
    float USALongitude = table.getFloat(row, 4);
    String countryName = table.getString(row,1);    

    //Mapped Within X-axis of the left side map box

    float mappedLatitude = map(USALatitude,-90, 90, 150, -150); // Latitude is in Y axis
    float mappedLongitude = map(USALongitude, -180, 180, -325, 325); // Longitude in X Axis
    x1 = mappedLongitude;
    y1 = mappedLatitude;
    z1 = 0;    

    float tripCountryLatitude = table.getFloat(row, 5);
    float tripCountryLongitude = table.getFloat(row, 6);     
    float tripLatitude = map(tripCountryLatitude, -90, 90, 150, -150); // In Y, same mapping
    float tripLongitude = map(tripCountryLongitude, -180, 180, 375, 1025); 

    // In X, having the position of the right box depending on the coordinates center
    x2 = tripLongitude;
    y2 = tripLatitude;
    z2 = 0;    

    float zOff = map(0, 0, height, 300, 0); // Move mouse up and down    

    float a = (x2-x1)/3;
    float b = (y2-y1)/3;

    stroke(stroke);
    noFill();

    bezier(x1, y1, z1,                 // First point
         x1 + a, y1 + b, z1 + zOff,  // First intermediate point
         x2 - a, y2 - b, z2 + zOff,  // Second intermediate point
         x2, y2, z2); 

    //rotate(PI); 
    stroke(255);
    fill(255);
    text(countryName, x2-10, y2+10, z2+20);
  }

  popMatrix();

}

  }
class Table {
  int rowCount;
  String[][] data;


  Table(String filename) {
    String[] rows = loadStrings(filename);
    data = new String[rows.length][];

    for (int i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      if (trim(rows[i]).length() == 0) {
        continue; // skip empty rows
      }
      if (rows[i].startsWith("#")) {
        continue;  // skip comment lines
      }

      // split the row on the tabs
      String[] pieces = split(rows[i], TAB);
      // copy to the table array
      data[rowCount] = pieces;
      rowCount++;

      // this could be done in one fell swoop via:
      //data[rowCount++] = split(rows[i], TAB);
    }
    // resize the 'data' array as necessary
    data = (String[][]) subset(data, 0, rowCount);
  }


  public int getRowCount() {
    return rowCount;
  }


  // find a row by its name, returns -1 if no row found
  public int getRowIndex(String name) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
      if (data[i][0].equals(name)) {
        return i;
      }
    }
    println("No row named '" + name + "' was found");
    return -1;
  }


  public String getRowName(int row) {
    return getString(row, 0);
  }


  public String getString(int rowIndex, int column) {
    return data[rowIndex][column];
  }


  public String getString(String rowName, int column) {
    return getString(getRowIndex(rowName), column);
  }


  public int getInt(String rowName, int column) {
    return parseInt(getString(rowName, column));
  }


  public int getInt(int rowIndex, int column) {
    return parseInt(getString(rowIndex, column));
  }


  public float getFloat(String rowName, int column) {
    return parseFloat(getString(rowName, column));
  }


  public float getFloat(int rowIndex, int column) {
    return parseFloat(getString(rowIndex, column));
  }


  public void setRowName(int row, String what) {
    data[row][0] = what;
  }


  public void setString(int rowIndex, int column, String what) {
    data[rowIndex][column] = what;
  }


  public void setString(String rowName, int column, String what) {
    int rowIndex = getRowIndex(rowName);
    data[rowIndex][column] = what;
  }


  public void setInt(int rowIndex, int column, int what) {
    data[rowIndex][column] = str(what);
  }


  public void setInt(String rowName, int column, int what) {
    int rowIndex = getRowIndex(rowName);
    data[rowIndex][column] = str(what);
  }


  public void setFloat(int rowIndex, int column, float what) {
    data[rowIndex][column] = str(what);
  }


  public void setFloat(String rowName, int column, float what) {
    int rowIndex = getRowIndex(rowName);
    data[rowIndex][column] = str(what);
  }  
}
  public void settings() {  size(1400, 800, "P3D"); }
  static public void main(String[] passedArgs) {
    String[] appletArgs = new String[] { "Two_Maps_Texture" };
    if (passedArgs != null) {
      PApplet.main(concat(appletArgs, passedArgs));
    } else {
      PApplet.main(appletArgs);
    }
  }
}
```

> java.lang.RuntimeException: The P3D renderer is not in the class path.
>     at processing.core.PApplet.makeGraphics(PApplet.java:2311)
>     at processing.core.PApplet.createPrimaryGraphics(PApplet.java:2345)
>     at processing.core.PApplet.initSurface(PApplet.java:10983)
>     at processing.core.PApplet.runSketch(PApplet.java:10922)
>     at processing.core.PApplet.main(PApplet.java:10620)
>     at Two_Maps_Texture.main(Two_Maps_Texture.java:355)

I've imported all the jar files like the resources tell me to but still I get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you add the jogl and gluegen libraries to the build path as well for `P3D`(OpenGL) renderer support.

Here's an example on OSX: use the [jar files](https://github.com/processing/processing/tree/master/core/library) specific to your platform (OS and CPU architecture)

[image: gluegen-rt and jogl jar libraries location in in the eclipse project]

They should be within the Processing install folder within `Java/core/library`.

Once you've added the relevant jogl and gluegen-rt jar files to the project and added them to the Build Path you should be able to compile with no errors

Answer (score 0):

When you set up your Processing app you need to to pass in the name of the renderer class you want to use to the size() function.

In the Processing IDE/environment for OpenGL you use `"P3D"`, but when you use a custom IDE like Eclipse you need to use `PConstants.P3D`. That is a string constant which value is `"processing.opengl.PGraphicsOpenGL"` - the name of the actual OpenGL render class.

```
public void settings() {
    size(W, H, processing.core.PConstants.P3D);
}
```